# Linux - Perl: Printing the content of the script I am executing

Tags: linux, perl

Is it possible to print the whole content of the script I am executing?

Since there are many things that will go on inside the script like the calling perl modules I will call in runtime (require "/dir/file";), the print lines I am executing inside an array (foreach(@array) {print "$_\n";}).

Why do I need this? To study the script generation I am making, especially when errors are occurring. Error occurred on line 2000 (even I have only 1 thousand lines of script).

Comment: "Error occurred on line 2000 (even I have only 1 thousand lines of script)." This doesn't make sense, and points to either a file mismatch or a source filter. Requiring outside files and running loops do not arbitrarily create new lines of source code.

Answer (score 4):

There are probably better ways to debug a script (the perl debugger, using `Carp::Always` to get stack traces with any errors and warnings), but nonetheless there are at least <strike>two</strike> three mechanisms for obtaining the source code of the running script.

1. Since `$0` contains the name of the file that perl is executing, you can read from it.

   ```
   open my $fh, '<', $0;
   my @this_script = <$fh>;
   close $fh;
   ```
2. If a script has the `__DATA__` or `__END__` token in its source, then Perl also sets up the `DATA` file handle. Initially, the `DATA` file handle points to the text after
   the `__DATA__` or `__END__` token, but it is actually opened to the whole source file, so you can `seek` to the beginning of that file handle and access the entire script.

   ```
   seek DATA, 0, 0;
   my @this_script = <DATA>;
   ```
3. HT Grinnz: the token `__FILE__` in any Perl source file refers to the name of the file that contains that token

   ```
   open my $fh, '<', __FILE__;
   my @this_file = <$fh>;
   close $fh;
   ```

Comment: I would recommend opening `__FILE__`, not `$0`, since `$0` can be modified and won't necessarily be the current file to begin with.